# How to change the email of the "Welcome to X Group" email in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to modify the email sender who sends out the "welcome to this group email" in sharepoint when adding someone to a group.

It was set to someone who no longer works at the company and I want to set it to a generic name, so instead of guywhodoesntworkhere@mycompany.com to mycompany@mycompany.com .

I looked around and it looks like this isn't possible, but I'm sure there is a way to do it by altering the source. Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance!
Dan

Comment: I think this question would fit perfectly on the new [Sharepoint](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) site of StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

This should be handled by the Outgoing Email Settings in Central Administration.  You can globally change the email addresses there.  Check "Step 4" of this blog post on how to get there:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pareshg/archive/2010/04/23/how-to-configure-incoming-and-outgoing-emails-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx